# Loading columns from file

Tags: c

I am a beginner and I have to write a program that reads a column from a file.I throw what I was able to write. I have no idea what to do to load only one selected column.And what to do with the size of the array.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 int main ()

 {
  FILE *pr;
  char fname[100];
  int i, n;


  char tablica[100][100];



  printf ("File name\n");
  scanf ("%s", &fname);
  pr = fopen(fname,"r");


  if (pr == NULL) 
  {
  printf ("can't load file\n");
  exit(-1);
  }

  printf ("column number\n");
  scanf ("%d",&i);
  if (i == NULL)
  { 
      printf ("no column\n");
  }



  while (!feof(pr)) 
  {
  fscanf(pr, "%s",&tablica[i]);
  printf ("%s\n",tablica[i]);
  }
  fclose (pr);
 }
```

Comment: I am not sure what the question is. You are not telling us what your exact problem is :)? What does this current code do wrong?

Comment: Can you show us a file example?

Comment: so you want to count no of column in file right?

Comment: Why so many blank lines?

Comment: Code must print out only one selected column. Now prints the entire file. 
Example file is :
col01 col02 col03 col04
aa 10 11 31
bb 20 21 32
cc 30 31 33
dd 40 41 43

Answer (score 0):

File loading is wrong as `scanf ("%s", &fname);` reads a file name to address of address `fname` which is wrong.

Try just passing base address of char array `fname` like, `scanf ("%s", fname);`